# Compilation of firefox extension with xulrunner-sdk-13.0

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a FF toolbar working in all previous versions.
 My toolbar partially written in C++. I've compiled the C++ part with xulrunner-sdk-13.0
Now it doesn't work.

My JS code,

```
if (!Components.classes['@some/SignedData;1'])
```

now returns false

Has something changed in Firefox 13.0 which explains this?

Comment: No. How about some details now? E.g., in which Firefox version are you *running* this extension?

Comment: @Wladimir: It worked on FF12 when compiled with xulrunner-sdk-12.0, but it doesn't work on any version when compiled with xulrunner-sdk-13.0. I've tried to compile it with ASLR enabled, but the classes still don't seem to load.

Comment: Binary XPCOM components work on one single Firefox version only - so your new version on Firefox 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next release 13.0.1 fixes the problem